# Creating a python table from key/counters text file

Tags: python, parsing, text-files

Text file example

```
<counter name="abcb">70324360</counter>
<counter name="efghij">1094</counter>
<counter name="klm">0</counter>
```

I want to create a function that will return the counter number(1094) when I call the counter name(efghij). I don't actually know where to start with that text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **xml** module, which is very closed to your file structure:

```
s = '''
<counter name="abcb">70324360</counter>
<counter name="efghij">1094</counter>
<counter name="klm">0</counter>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring('<root>' + s + '</root>')

def get_counter(name):
    for node in tree.iter('counter'):
        if node.attrib.get('name') == name:
            return node.text
```

Usage:

```
get_counter('klm')

'0'
```

In case you're reading the source from file, just change to this and wrap with a `<root>` node:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

tree = ET.fromstring('<root>' + s + '</root>')
...
```

**As a side note**: **fromstring()** will fail if it hasn't got a **root** node, which you can simply wrap it before parsing.

Comment: This is excellent Anzel. I have learned something new today. I just went over the elements xml api documentation and this is super helpful. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @FJC, glad it helps, we've been through that stage too ;)

Comment: I must point out the code above works like a charm under Python 2.7.6 that I have. If you get error like "AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'" use getiterator() instead of iter() lower versions of python will not take iter. Ran into that issue with 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a function, you can create a `dict` to hold the counters.  Read the text file ('file.txt' in this case) and use `re` to extract the data from each line.

```
import re

counter = {}
re_counter = re.compile(r'name="(\w+)">(\d+)')
for line in open('file.txt'):
    match = re_counter.search(line)
    if match:
        counter[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
print counter["efghij"]
```